# Spring IO Platform 2.0 - Themes/Changes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Noticed that there is a 2.0 version of the [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) available as a snapshot.  I am looking to understand what might be driving the major version number change.  Can someone with better insight into the changes share the themes here (or point to somewhere where this is better documented)?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "Upgrading" section of the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#upgrading-removal

Some dependencies were removed, which leads to a major version, since it's a breaking change.